# Java: Getting an array of ENUM elements

Tags: java, arrays, enums

Is there a better way of creating arrays from elements of an enum:

```
    public static enum LOGICAL {
        AND ("&", "AND"),
        OR ("||", "OR");

        public final String symbol;
        public final String label;

        LOGICAL(String symbol, String label) {
            this.symbol=symbol;
            this.label=label;
        }
    }

    public static final String[] LOGICAL_NAMES = new String[LOGICAL.values().length];
    static{
        for(int i=0; i<LOGICAL.values().length; i++)
            LOGICAL_NAMES[i]=LOGICAL.values()[i].symbol;
    }

    public static final String[] LOGICAL_LABELS = new String[LOGICAL.values().length];
    static{
        for(int i=0; i<LOGICAL.values().length; i++)
            LOGICAL_LABELS[i]=LOGICAL.values()[i].label;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That seems the proper way. Even if there was some utility, it would rely on reflection

If you are using it often cache it in the enum

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "caching". Move the static arrays to the enum body?

Comment: Store it in a field so that you don't compute it everytime

Comment: I was convinced that this code would only run ONCE (on the first access to the class).

Comment: ah, yes - I missed the constant definition. So you are already caching it.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I wouldn't expose them as an array, whose contents can be changed by anyone. I'd probably use an unmodifiable list instead - and *probably* expose that via a property rather than as a field. The initialization would be something like this:

```
private static final List<String> labels;
private static final List<String> values;

static
{
    List<String> mutableLabels = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> mutableValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (LOGICAL x : LOGICAL.values())
    {
         mutableLabels.add(x.label);
         mutableValues.add(x.value);
    }
    labels = Collections.unmodifiableList(mutableLabels);
    values = Collections.unmodifiableList(mutableValues);
}
```

(If you're already using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) you might even want to use `ImmutableList` instead, and expose the collections that way to make it clear that they *are* immutable.)

Comment: Yes! I wish there is a ImmutableList in standard Java API.

Answer (score 2):

If you use your values very frequently and your enumeration gets bigger use Maps. Declare the following in your class.

```
private static EnumMap<LOGICAL,String> symbols = new EnumMap<LOGICAL, String>(LOGICAL.class);
```

and then just below it:

```
static{
    for(LOGICAL i : LOGICAL.values().)
        symbols.put(i, i.symbol);
}
```

then you can use `symbols.values()` or `symbols.get(LOGICAL.AND)` etc.